# Pass currently selected element in devtools to javascript in electron

Tags: electron

I want to let the user select a html element via the devtools in electron. I know that you can get this with the variable $0. The problem is that it's only accessible in the dev tools console.

I looked into the Chrome DevTools Protocol and found Runtime.evaluate which has a paramter to include the command line api. This seems to work with everything except $0 though. I can call clear(), $(), and other stuff. But $0 is undefined.

```
let debug = mainWindow.webContents.debugger;
debug.attach();

mainWindow.webContents.on("devtools-opened", () => {
    devToolsOpen = true;
    myEmitter.emit("devtoolsready");
});

mainWindow.webContents.on("devtools-closed", () => {
    devToolsOpen = false;
});

//coords from renderer mouse event
ipcMain.on("inspectelement", (event, pageX, pageY) => {
    mainWindow.webContents.inspectElement(pageX, pageY);
    //if the devtools are not ready yet, wait for the event before executing the function
    if (devToolsOpen === false) {
        myEmitter.once("devtoolsready", devToolsFunction)
    }
    else {
        devToolsFunction();
    }

    async function devToolsFunction() {

        let backendNodeId = (await debug.sendCommand("DOM.getNodeForLocation", { x: pageX, y: pageY })).backendNodeId;
        let resolvedNode = (await debug.sendCommand("DOM.resolveNode", { backendNodeId: backendNodeId }));
        let js$0False = (await debug.sendCommand("Runtime.evaluate", { expression: "alert($0)", includeCommandLineAPI: false }));
        let js$0True = (await debug.sendCommand("Runtime.evaluate", { expression: "alert($0)", includeCommandLineAPI: true }));

        console.log(backendNodeId);
        console.log(resolvedNode);
        //Fails because $0 is not defined, does not alert
        console.log(js$0False);
        //$0 is set to undefined
        console.log(js$0True);
    }
});
```

I also tried getting to the element through internal dom representations with Dom.getNodeForLocation but I don't know how I should get to the actual element with that.

$0 being undefined seems like a bug to me, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some more experimenting, it seems like the devtools and the devtools protocol do not share $0. The workaround is to push the selected node to the frontend and then call setInspectedNode. After this the variable will be set and accessible.

```
//required for subsequent calls. Not sure if it is needed for every call but maybe 
//it does not update automaticly so it stays here
let doc = (await debug.sendCommand("DOM.getDocument"));

//backend id of the node at mouse position
let backendNodeId = (await debug.sendCommand("DOM.getNodeForLocation", { x: pageX, y: pageY })).backendNodeId;

//needed to push the backend node to the fron
let front = (await debug.sendCommand("DOM.pushNodesByBackendIdsToFrontend", { backendNodeIds: [backendNodeId] }));

//it seems like the devtools context and this one do not share $0.
//Because of this you need to call setInspectedNode, after which it will be set and accessible
let inspect = (await debug.sendCommand("DOM.setInspectedNode", { nodeId: front.nodeIds[0] }));

//write $0 to another var accessable from a normal js context
let js$0True = (await debug.sendCommand("Runtime.evaluate", { expression: "selectedNode = $0", includeCommandLineAPI: true }));
```

Comment: This was the only useful Google search results that explains how to do it.  It is incredible that I am the first to up-vote this answer!  Please mark this answer as accepted.  There is no shame in answering your own question!

Comment: @kevinarpe totally agree, was digging around a lot until found this, nice solution!